# Reduce view hierarchy in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This is one line in a vertically orientated layout.

[image]

I create it with this xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="+@id/lineWrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_item_bg"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="+@id/leftWrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:text="Header Title"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_sub_title"
            android:text="Header Sub-title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightWrapper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:paddingRight="17dp"
            android:text="Value"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This takes heavy use of linear layouts. Is there a way to achieve the same but with less xml or better performance?

Comment: With a RelativeLayout

Comment: @algui91 show me how please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (untested)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_item_bg"
    android:clickable="false"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="27dp"
        android:text="Value"
        android:textSize="26sp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt_value"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="Header Title"
        android:textSize="19sp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_sub_title"
        android:text="Header Sub-title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt_value"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: One problem, txt_value is not centered vertically in lineWrapper

Comment: Change this: `android:gravity="center|right"` to: `android:gravity="right|center_vertical"`

Comment: Does not change anything

Comment: OK, let me do some testing. back in minutes.

Comment: haha yeah, you might try snapshot next time, will be faster. However I solved it by adding android:layout_centerInParent="true" to txt_value. Thanky you!!

Comment: OK, solved. The TextView height has to be `match_parent` (or a fixed value in dp), instead of `wrap_content`

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** please always assign resource id like  `android:id="@+id/leftWrapper"` instead  `android:id="+@id/leftWrapper"`  , So make it correct.

You can use Relative layout where you need to place the item's in co-relation with each other. For more [see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

**Use this code to achieve the same:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lineWrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="Header Title"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_sub_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="Header Sub-title"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:paddingRight="17dp"
        android:text="Value"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,will work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lineWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_item_bg"
    android:clickable="false"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingRight="27dp"
        android:text="Value"
        android:textSize="26sp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_value"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="Header Title"
        android:textSize="19sp"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_sub_title"
        android:text="Header Sub-title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_title"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_value"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```